# Ctags/Cscope/other taking includes and makefile into account when building DB

Tags: c, scope, ctags

By default, as far as I can see, ctags and cscope parse a set of C files and build a Database/index (e.g. ctags files...) about the identifiers/macros... met during parsing.

When, later, the user asks about a given identifier, he is given a list of possible locations for the declaration of the identifier. The user can then pick a choice from the list and see the definition of the identifier.

Now, if, for instance, you ask for identifier "dev" in the linux kernel, the list to choose from is more than 1500 entries long!

In reality, only one definition is used at a time. The rest is excluded at build time, due to `#includes`(which other files are included or not) or make rules (which object are linked together).

Is there a way to tell Ctags/ Cscope (or any other) to take `#includes` and `Makefiles` into account to make a better list? Hopefully just leaving the only valid reference in the list, or at least ranking the list by higher probability order...

I am aware, that the build options might impact this and that the tool (Ctags, Cscope...) cannot guess those in advance. Also the build environement might be very complicated or incomplete/missing when Ctag/Cscope is used... but it sounds to me that giving it a try would probably result in a better situation than just presenting a flat list of sometimes over 1000 entries to choose from...

Or is there any reason not to do so, that I am obviously missing...

Comment: I think this should be done in the tool that uses the tags file generated by such programs to filter only the relevant entries.